# Yii 2 migrations for test database

Tags: php, testing, yii2, codeception

I'm failing to see a clear way to do this, although I can see it being reiterated multiple times in the documentation, specifically:

> Use yii migrate tool to upgrade your test database to the latest version;

found in http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-test-fixture.html#summary (just to give an example)

What happens is that no matter how I configure the `_console.php` and `_config.php` within my `tests/unit` folder, if I run the migration tool is picking up the main app db:

```
$ cd tests/unit
$ ../../yii migrate/up
Yii Migration Tool (based on Yii v2.0.0-dev)

No new migration found. Your system is up-to-date.
```

And yes, the test database is correctly configured (running tests will throw an error saying there are no tables).
I can obviously create the db structure myself, but this is all about getting this feature work as it should.

I'm currently using the **Basic** app installed via composer.

Comment: just to be clear, I also fail to see a way to name the test db by running `yii migrate/up --db=X`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[edit] updated the answer to reflect the current version of Yii2

Just posting the correct answer as I found it myself and I feel a bit stupid as it was under my eyes.

There's another `yii` commandline within the test folder directory, which means you can easily do:

```
$ cd tests/codeception/bin
$ chmod a+x yii
$ yii migrate/up
```

and it will automatically use the database you've specified in `tests/codeception/config/config.php`.

Enjoy

Answer (score 17):

Just using `yii_test migrate` for Yii2.

Comment: This seems the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

To apply migrations for test database in Yii2 run this command in project's directory:

```
php tests/bin/yii migrate
```

Comment: As far as I can see that only creates the migration table. What about the user table for example?